# Displaying small part of content - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

This is my loop code.

```
<?php $posts = get_posts ("orderby=date&numberposts=1"); ?> 
            <?php if ($posts) : ?>
            <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata ($post); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" d="center-news">
                <div class="center-news-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/example.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="center-news-text">
                    <div class="center-news-title"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></div>
                    <div class="center-news-info">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

If the the post have long content it will break the html. I need to display a little part of content. Is it possible?

Comment: What code you have tried till now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

it display the first 55 words of the post's content

refer codex [the_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) for more details

Comment: and you can set the number of characters of the excerpt as well

Comment: yes as said by @BojanaŠekeljić you can also set the number of characters as you want in the excerpt

Answer (score 4):

you can try this code

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', substr(get_the_content(), 0, 200) ); ?>
```